# Entity Framework Core : how can I use DateDiff in Linq?

Tags: sql, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to create a query in EF Core like this :

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, FromDate, ToDate)) AS Diff 
FROM Table1
```

The above query is for T-SQL - how can I create a query in Linq?

Comment: What version of EF (EF 6.x, EF Core 2.0 / 2.x / 3.x)? You would use `EntityFunctions` or `DbFunctions` `DiffDays` method.

Comment: @NetMage I use EF Core 3.1

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using `DbFunctions`, accessed via `EF.Functions`, you can call `DateDiffDay`:

```
var ans = from t in Table1
          group t by 1 into tg
          select tg.Sum(r => EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(r.FromDate, r.ToDate));
```

My [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you with some translation issues in the future.

PS: As noted by @B12Toaster, particular `EF.Functions` methods are provider specific and `DataDiffDay` is specific to MS SQL Server.

Comment: Just a remark: "DateDiffDay() is an SQL Server-specific extension and doesn't work when using Npgsql." – https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/473#issuecomment-404829344

Comment: @B12Toaster Yes, that seems to be a difference from EF 6.x where certain functions were required of every provider. I think I would prefer if EF Core also has a base of required translations as the current model makes being agnostic to database engine impossible.